Why does this dehumidifer only work when the fan is set to LOW?
Could use some help troubleshooting this Kenmore dehumidifier.   It's 15-20 years old.  Today it stopped doing its job.  It was louder than usual and we noticed that there was no air coming out the back.  Figuring the fan was somehow broken, I opened it up and poked around.

The fan blades spin freely, so there is no ice/other obstruction.  And you can see that the blades aren't broken.  I plugged it in and heard it buzzing again.  I gave the fan a manual spin and it kept going on its own.  I poked around more and discovered that when the fan speed on the front panel is set to LOW, the fan runs normally.  As soon as you switch it to HIGH, the fan stops.  Anyone know whether this is something like a simple switching component or capacitor that I could fix on my own, or a sign that the motor is failing?  If the motor is failing I'll assume it's not worth trying to repair.
Relatedly, is it safe to run with the fan on LOW?

I have once replaced the fan motor in a dehumidifier - it just happened to be compatible with the one in a cheap desk fan I rarely used.  I got about another 5 years out of it before the compressor died
